# Пузырьковая сортировка

Tags: сортировка, c++

Наконец дошел до массивов, разбираюсь с сортировкой массивов. Объясните, пожалуйста, эту строчку. Почему n - 1?

```
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
{
    // Почему n - 1?
    for (int y = 0; y < n - 1; y++)
    {
        if (array[y] > array[y + 1])
        {
            int temp = array[y + 1];

            array[y + 1] = array[y];
            array[y] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Если бы цикл был до **n**, то последнее значение **y**, которое мы рассматриваем **y = n - 1**, что соответствует последнему элементу массива (элемента с индексом **n** у нас нет, потому что индексация с **0**).

при **y = n - 1**:

```
if (array[y] > array[y + 1])
```

примет вид

```
if (array[n - 1] > array[n])
```

Мы сравниваем последний элемент и элемент, которого **нет**, что было бы ошибкой.

Comment: То есть мы находим максимальный элемент, переносим его в конец и сдвигаемся влево на один элемент?

Comment: ну да, получается так.
<br><a href="http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.8B_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.B0">пример работы алгоритма</a>.

Comment: Для изучения сортировок есть <a href="http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/">хороший сайт</a> с визуализацией работы каждого алгоритма. Представлены наиболее используемые сортировки.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/vis , там много визуализаций различных алгоритмов